# Updating Custom Interactive Map

Tags: css, dictionary, background

I'm running into an issue. I'm trying to rewrite an old flash/xml map using CSS. I have a big jpg of the map, which is the background. I'm able to lay the icons out, where they need to be.

The problem I'm having is centering the whole thing on the page. Ideally, the map would be centered and the user would be able to click and drag the background image to look at the various sections, the way Google Maps or something works.

How can I do this, or what is this effect called, so I can google it more in depth. Searching "map" at all gives results about customizing Google Maps. Which isn't what I'm trying to do. I'm thinking it'll involve absolute positioning and and viewports, but I don't know *exactly* how to code it.

Should I just make a frame?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Leaflet will probably solve the problem. http://leafletjs.com/